# Emrfs file sync with s3 not working

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

After running a spark job on an Amazon EMR cluster, I deleted the output files directly from s3 and tried to rerun the job again. I received the following error upon trying to write to parquet file format on s3 using sqlContext.write:

```
'bucket/folder' present in the metadata but not s3
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(ConsistencyCheckerS3FileSystem.java:455)
```

I tried running

```
emrfs sync s3://bucket/folder
```

which did not appear to resolve the error even though it did remove some records from the DynamoDB instance that keeps track of the metadata. Not sure what else I can try. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to run

```
emrfs delete s3://bucket/folder
```

first before running sync. Running the above solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue..  sync does not do anything useful when files are deleted manually from s3.  Documentation is plain wrong and misleading.

Comment: Got the same issue, agreed the documentation is very unclear about it.

Answer (score 22):

Mostly the consistent problem comes due to retry logic in spark and hadoop systems. When a process of creating a file on s3 failed, but it already updated in the dynamodb. when the hadoop process restarts the process as the entry is already present in the dynamodb. It throws the consistent error.

If you want to delete the metadata of s3 which is stored in the dynamaoDB, whose objects are already removed.
This are the steps,
**Delete all the metadata**

Deletes all the objects in the path, 
emrfs delete uses the hash function to delete the records, so it may delete unwanted entries also, so we are doing the import and sync in the consequent steps

```
emrfs delete   s3://path
```

**Retrieves the metadata for the objects that are physically present in s3 into dynamo db**

```
emrfs import s3://path
```

**Sync the data between s3 and the metadata.**

```
emrfs sync s3://path
```

**After all the operations, to see whether that particular object is present in both s3 and metadata**

```
emrfs diff s3://path
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-cli-reference.html

Comment: I wonder if that ever helped anyone? I'm on EMR 5.21.0 and spark-shell will only see part of the files in a bucket, no matter what I do.

Comment: @ViacheslavRodionov May be those files has the permission issue

Comment: For some reason, all these commands hung for minutes for me, even on very small file scopes (long s3 prefixes), so I gave up on this and deleted from the dynamodb table in seconds, but that still didn't invalidate the local cache on the emr cluster. :(

Comment: Ok, when this issue happened again (with different data), I gave these commands more time to complete and they finished. It took about an hour for a prefix with about 2 dozen files in it. So, larger ones could potentially take a lot longer (or maybe it's just based on the total DynamoDB table size for a single scan - IDK).

Comment: Just now forced to do another one that was literally just one key/object/file and took just as long, so I'm now going to assume it's based on the size of scanning (my) emrfs dynamodb table for each of the above commands). Yours might be bigger/slower or smaller/faster.

Comment: Wonder whether there's a way to trim out unused s3 objects just to make the emrfs dynamoDB table scans quicker. If I just did the `delete` or maybe the `delete` and `sync` steps on things I did NOT want to track in EMRFS, would that cause any problems. What if I changed my mind and wanted to track those things later after all - would it cause problems then?

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this page because I was getting the error "key is marked as directory in metadata but is file in s3" and was very puzzled. I think what happened is that I accidentally created both a file and directory by the same name. By deleting the file it solved my issue:

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket/directory_name_without_trailing_slash
```

Comment: You should probably ask and and then answer your own question as this is a separate issue...