# emrfs sync and import gets stuck and not working

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I keep getting the inconstancy error while running spark jobs with s3 source and when i run emrfs sync or emrfs import. it runs for a certain duration of time (added 10624 s3key) and just gets stuck. Also Spark read doesn't run and throws inconsistency error/exception after waiting for couple of minutes. Any idea why this happens and how to avoid the issue?

usecase: reading about 20TB of data from s3 and perform sorting and window operations.

actions performed:

emrfs delete --metadata-name EmrFSMetaTbl s3://bucket/prefix-to-read/

emrfs import --metadata-name EmrFSMetaTbl s3://bucket/prefix-to-read/

Tried dropping the metadata table and still I get inconsistency error. 
I have already tried the approach given in [Emrfs file sync with s3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823283/emrfs-file-sync-with-s3-not-working)

Comment: to my understanding u shouldnt worry abt emrfs-consistancy ; or do any sync manually. EMR FS keeps metadata of the s3 data in dynamo db (u can open u dynamo db and u will see a table there); my understanding: when writing to s3 EMR writes to dynamo also, and if u try to modify/ dlete some objects from s3; then the EMR fs is in-consistant.

Answer (score 3):

The issue happens when you delete a huge number of files from S3 (mine was almost million files of very small size) use the following below command to sync up the metadata of the file structure with DynamoDB. Additional commands can be viewed in the [URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-cli-reference.html)

```
emrfs sync s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/cloudfront
```

Incase this issue keeps recurring, create a new cluster and delete the EMRFS dynamoDB Table. This solved my issue